# Why is this ContentNote test failing?

Tags: apex, contentnote

The assertion in this test - a stripped down version of a bigger to illustrate the specific problem - that has the comment:

> // This assertion fails: 'Hello' is returned not 'World'

fails:

```
@IsTest
private class ContentNoteProblem {

    @IsTest
    static void content() {

        String content = 'Hello';
        ContentNote note = new ContentNote(
            Title = 'Test',
            Content = Blob.valueOf(content)
        );
        insert note;

        System.assertEquals(content, queryContent(note.Id));

        String newContent = 'World';
        note.Content = Blob.valueOf(newContent);
        update note;

        // This assertion fails: 'Hello' is returned not 'World'
        System.assertEquals(newContent, queryContent(note.Id));
    }

    private static String queryContent(Id noteId) {
        return [
            select Content
            from ContentNote
            where Id = :noteId
        ].Content.toString();
    }
}
```

(To run this you need "Enable Notes" checked in Setup -> Customize -> Notes -> Note Settings.)

Why does this fail - what am I missing? Something to do with content versioning?

Comment: I wonder if it's related to the odd way in which ContentNote is a facade over ContentDocument and ContentVersion. If you query via the latter, does the right result surface?

Comment: Not completely sure if this is an issue with how "update" works in apex context for ContentNote but was trying few things on your test class and found out this, if at all it helps. If I query the ContentVersion after the update call, I get only 1 result, I expected it should have returned 2 (I verified it from UI and the version number does get incremented with updates on the note). Now if I insert a new ContentNote (instead of an update) with the same Title, the assertion works fine. And when I query the ContentVersion, I get expected 2 results.

Comment: Further notes. The update does seem to work correctly but looks like the problem lies while fetching the record. Tried this from developer console and the behavior was similar. Inserted a note, and then updated the value, upon fetching the content it always returns the old value. However could see that the value that was updated is reflected from UI. So wonder if there's really something which is not behaving as expected in apex context.

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks for your comment. I've had to move on from this to focus on getting some work finished this week so have worked around it in my real test cases. Hopefully someone who has been through this will post a simple answer I can employ.

Comment: @JayantDas Yeah it doesn't seem to be a problem in the real UI just in tests. Might be something transaction related or perhaps something in the Apex test environment is different. Thank-you very much for your efforts on this.

Comment: I suspect it's not working because unless you're overwriting `content` (in which case, use the same var name), you should be appending `newContent` to `content` before performing the update operation. Notes are intended to be updateable so additional info can be added to them, not just so they can be overwritten/replaced with new versions like general content.

Comment: @crmprogdev The content appears to just be a Blob so I don't understand why change should be any different to append?

Comment: @KeithC `ContentNote` is based on `ContentVersion`. I suggest you check to see if there's a `ContentVersion.ContentBodyId` associated with the ContentNote's Body. The docs say only the `ContentNote.Body` and `ContentNote.Title` are updateable.

Comment: @crmprogdev Agreed this may be something to do with ContentVersion. However, this [ContentNote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm) says `Content` is updatable.

Comment: @KeithC My info came from the Object Reference for [ContentNote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm). This seemed pretty explicit. Pick your poison. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the only way to reliably update is to add a new `ContentVersion`.